# RTL88x2BU driver is compatible with the RTL8822CU chipset?

Tags: 20.04, wireless

RTL88x2BU driver is compatible with the RTL8822CU chipset ?

Comment: In order to find out, let's compare the usb.id of your device with the alias fields in the driver. Start by editing your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.